# Design a complex access/permissions system, what approach should I take

Tags: web-applications, acl, access-control, rbac

I am using PHP+MySQL right now, but really can adopt any tool out there.

I have a system with about 50000 users which are arranged into groups, which are arranged into departments which are arranged into organizations.

I have in my system content packages. Each package has a specific permission. i.e. each package is either

1. public (world),
2. consortium (all registered to my system)
3. private (can be accessed by any combinations of single users + group + department + organization)

To make things harder, Each content might have a pre-requisite content, means you can't take content B before you took content A (courses in a university...).

I am wondering how to manage it, right now every thing is in MySQL and works fine, just that each time I create a content with pre-requisite I must be able to choose as pre-requisite only those content pieces with more permissive access, which means a lot of computations for each piece I have in the system (I have a few thousands).

Now, Imagine I have content c which depends on B which depends on A...
And what is the catalog  that I show to each user? Imaging the calculation I have to do for each content piece when the user searches the entire system.

Any direction/suggestion/known systems that do that already?

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question is over 2 years and that by now you have likely solved your issue. Still, here are some pointers to help solve the problem you were faced with.

You need to externalize your authorization logic and your business logic. This means you want to look into business rules engines and authorization rules engines.

The standards in that space are BPEL (for business processes) and XACML (for authorization).

You'd use XACML to determine who can view / edit / take certain content. You'd use BPEL (or BPM languages) to determine the rules about taking a course before you can take another.